# DNS zone files with more than one name pointing to the same IP

Tags: networking, dns, ip, definition

I have set up a local DNS and the forward zone file looks like this:

$TTL 86400

@   IN  SOA     ns0.mylocal.loc. root.mylocal.loc. (

```
    2011071001  ;Serial
    3600        ;Refresh
    1800        ;Retry
    604800      ;Expire
    86400       ;Minimum TTL
```

)

@   IN  NS          ns0.mylocal.loc.

@   IN  NS          ns1.mylocal.loc.

@   IN  A           192.168.100.58

@   IN  A           192.168.100.59

@   IN  A           192.168.100.100

@   IN  A           192.168.100.125

ns0                      IN A   192.168.100.58

ns1                      IN A   192.168.100.59

srv2                     IN A   192.168.100.100

srv3.mylocal.loc.        IN A   192.168.100.125

srv4.mylocal.loc.        IN A   192.168.100.125

srv5.mylocal.loc.        IN A   192.168.100.125

Is this a correct form for declaring? Is there any other way to declare multiple names linked to one IP by means of the DNS?